# How to do a replace with backreferences, when the number of occurences is unknown?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

In order to make a few corrections to a .tex file generated by Bookdown, I need to replace occurrences of `}{` with `,` when it is used in a citation, i.e.

```
s <- "Text.\\autocites{REF1}{REF2}{REF3}. More text \\autocites{REF4}{REF5} and \\begin{tabular}{ll}"
```

Should become

```
"Text.\\autocites{REF1,REF2,REF3}. More text \\autocites{REF4,REF5} and \\begin{tabular}{ll}
```

Because I need to keep the references I tried to look into backreferences, but I cannot seem to get it right, because the number of groups to match is unknown beforehand. Also, I cannot do `stringr::str_replace_all(s, "\\}\\{", ",")`, because `}{` occurs in other places in the document as well.

My best approach so far, is to use a look-behind to only do the replace when the occurence is after `\\autocites`, but then I cannot get the backreferences  and grouping right:

```
stringr::str_replace_all(s, "(?<=\\\\autocites\\{)([:alnum:]+)(\\}\\{)", "\\1,")
[1] "Text.\\autocites{REF1,REF2}{REF3}. More text \\autocites{REF4,REF5} and \\begin{tabular}{ll}"

stringr::str_replace_all(s, "(?<=\\\\autocites\\{)([:alnum:]+)((\\}\\{)([:alnum:]+))*", "\\1,\\4")
[1] "Text.\\autocites{REF1,REF3}. More text \\autocites{REF4,REF5} and \\begin{tabular}{ll}"
```

I might be missing some completely obvious approach, so I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool problem - I got to learn a new trick with `str_replace`.  You can make the return value a function, and it applies the function to the strings you've picked out.

```
replace_brakets <- function(str) {
  str_replace_all(str, "\\}\\{", ",")
}

s %>% str_replace_all("(?<=\\\\autocites\\{)([:alnum:]+\\}\\{)+", replace_brakets)
# [1] "Text.\\autocites{REF1,REF2,REF3}. More text \\autocites{REF4,REF5} and \\begin{tabular}{ll}"
```

Comment: Both suggested solutions are clever since they are able to apply a function before replacing, which I did not know was possible. That helped a lot with the nested groups I was otherwise trying to conceive (I am not even sure that it is possible). My final solution ended up being Melissas approach, but with G. Grothendiecks regex, since the replacement function removes the need for the look-behind. `stringr::str_replace_all(s, "(autocites.*?\\}($|[^{]))", function(x) stringr::str_replace_all(x, "\\}\\{", ","))`

Answer (score 2):

`pat` matches

- `autocites` followed by
- the shortest string that ends in `}` and is
- followed by end of string or a non-`{`

It then uses `gsubfn` to replace each occurrence of `}{` in that with a comma.  It uses formula notation to express the replacement function -- the body of the function is on the RHS of the `~` and because the body contains `..1` the arguments are taken to be `...` .  It does not use zero width lookahead or lookbehind.

```
library(gsubfn)

pat <- "(autocites.*?\\}($|[^{]))"
gsubfn(pat, ~ gsub("}{", ",", ..1, fixed = TRUE), s)
```

giving:

```
[1] "Text.\\autocites{REF1,REF2,REF3}. More text \\autocites{REF4,REF5} and \\begin{tabular}{ll}"
```

### Variation

One minor simplificaiton of the regular expression shown above is to  remove the outer parentheses from `pat` and instead specify `backref = 0`  in `gsubfn`.  That tells it to pass the entire match to the function.  We could use `..1` to specify the argument as above but since we know that there is necessarily only one argument passed we can specify it as `x` in the body of the function.  Any variable name would do as it assumes that any free variable is an argument.  The output would be the same as above.

```
pat2 <- "autocites.*?\\}($|[^{])"
gsubfn(pat2, ~ gsub("}{", ",", x, fixed = TRUE), s, backref = 0)
```